# How to sort array items by longitude latitude distance in javascripts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, latitude-longitude, geo

I am having following JSON array of 6 locations. Is there any way sort these based on longitude and latitude where nearby locations come next in the array?

```
[
{"id" : 279, "longitude":79.853239,"latitude":6.912283},
{"id" : 284, "longitude":79.865699,"latitude":6.885697},
{"id" : 13,  "longitude":79.851187,"latitude":6.912220},
{"id" : 282, "longitude":79.858904,"latitude":6.871041},
{"id" : 281, "longitude":79.853346,"latitude":6.899757},
{"id" : 16,  "longitude":79.854786,"latitude":6.894039}
]
```

Sorting can be started from first item and result should be something like this

```
[
{"id" : 279, "longitute":79.853239,"latitude":6.912283},
{"id" : 13,  "longitute":79.851187,"latitude":6.912220},
{"id" : 281, "longitute":79.853346,"latitude":6.899757},
{"id" : 16,  "longitute":79.854786,"latitude":6.894039},
{"id" : 284, "longitute":79.865699,"latitude":6.885697},
{"id" : 282, "longitute":79.858904,"latitude":6.871041}
]
```

Comment: if the first item is id=279 next item of the array should be nearest to first one (In this case it is id=13). then it should b nearest to id=13

Comment: So if you are sorting by distance from one another, how would you choose which is first and which is last?

Comment: As first element we can take first item, then based on that item we can sort next items. As i explained above if first item is id=279, then nearest one for that will be the second item which is id=13, then third item should be nearest to id=13.

Comment: So - create another array which starts with `0` and every next element contains distance from 1st element to the every other

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Problem resolved by adding another attribute called distance. Used following function to calculate distance between two points

```js
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
  var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
  var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
  var theta = lon1-lon2
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  dist = Math.acos(dist)
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
  if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
  if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
  return dist
}
```

Then calculated distance for each item in the array by using above function. Then sorted array by distance.

```
for ( i = 0; i < uniqueNodes.length; i++) {
  uniqueNodes[i]["distance"] = calculateDistance(uniqueNodes[0]["latitude"],uniqueNodes[0]["longitute"],uniqueNodes[i]["latitude"],uniqueNodes[i]["longitute"],"K");
}

uniqueNodes.sort(function(a, b) { 
  return a.distance - b.distance;
});
```

Comment: The calculateDistance function defines radlon1 and radlon2, but never uses them. Is that a problem for the algorithm?

Comment: This use the *Spherical Law of Cosines* https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. What is the meaning of units ? K for km ? and N for Imperial units / miles ?

Comment: very useful could you please explain this. how do we change uniqueNodes[0]["latitude"] to next closest location so that it will find its next closest location and so on?

Comment: @KevinNewman No, the `radllon2` and `radlong2` can be removed.

@solsTiCe It appears K = km and N = nautical miles. You can remove the unit parameter altogether if you are using this for sorting.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone else looking to do this, if you have the longitude and latitude avaliable, you can just sort linearly on it to get a simple line diagram like below. this will give you a rise/run linear result.

```
var $array = [
[79.853239, 6.912283, 279],
[79.851187, 6.912220, 13],
[79.853346, 6.899757, 281],
[79.854786, 6.894039, 16],
[79.865699, 6.885697, 284],
[79.858904, 6.87104, 282]
]

function sortLngLat(a, b){
var x = a[0] / a[1];
var y = b[0] / b[1];
}
var sortedArray = $array.sort(sortLngLat);
console.log(sortedArray);
```

output should be like graph below and you can tweak your values with negatives and positives to get different angles and directions.

```
 ---------------
|       |  /    |
| -1/1  | / 1/1 |
|       |/      |
|--------------
|      /|       |
|-1/-1/ | 1/-1  |
|    /  |       |
 ---------------
```

Answer (score 2):

For sorting we only need to calculate the *relative* distances between points. This allows for some **performance** optimizations. You *don't* need to multiply by the earth's radius and you *don't* need to take the square root of the squared differences.

```js
// define local constants for frequently used functions
const asin = Math.asin
const cos = Math.cos
const sin = Math.sin
const PI_180 = Math.PI / 180

function hav(x) {
  const s = sin(x / 2)
  return s * s
}

function relativeHaversineDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  const aLatRad = lat1 * PI_180
  const bLatRad = lat2 * PI_180
  const aLngRad = lon1 * PI_180
  const bLngRad = lon2 * PI_180

  const ht = hav(bLatRad - aLatRad) + cos(aLatRad) * cos(bLatRad) * hav(bLngRad - aLngRad)
  // since we're only interested in relative differences,
  // there is no need to multiply by earth radius or to sqrt the squared differences
  return asin(ht)
}

const locations = [
  { "id": 279, "longitude": 79.853239, "latitude": 6.912283 },
  { "id": 284, "longitude": 79.865699, "latitude": 6.885697 },
  { "id": 13, "longitude": 79.851187, "latitude": 6.912220 },
  { "id": 282, "longitude": 79.858904, "latitude": 6.871041 },
  { "id": 281, "longitude": 79.853346, "latitude": 6.899757 },
  { "id": 16, "longitude": 79.854786, "latitude": 6.894039 }
]

const distanceTo = {
  "id": 279,
  "longitude": 79.853239,
  "latitude": 6.912283
}
const sorted = locations.sort((a, b) => relativeHaversineDistance(a.latitude, a.longitude, distanceTo.latitude, distanceTo.longitude) - relativeHaversineDistance(b.latitude, b.longitude, distanceTo.latitude, distanceTo.longitude))

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one:

```
 function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    const R = 6371e3; // metres
    const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180; // φ, λ in radians
    const φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI / 180;
    const Δφ = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
    const Δλ = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
    const a = Math.sin(Δφ / 2) * Math.sin(Δφ / 2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ / 2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2);
    const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return R * c // in metres
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could loop through the array, and nest another loop that finds the nearest one.

```
var finalArray = [];

while(entries){
  //for each item
  while(what's left){
    //find the nearest against the current item
    //push to final
  }
}
```

This assumes that the very first in the array is the point of reference, that what comes next would be the nearest to that point, and so on.