# How can i get nearlest location from the array with current location?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps for render Google map. I had a current location and i have an array with some place location. The question is how can i get the nearlest from current location with an array . Can i have some example to do it. Thank so much

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452059/sort-data-by-closest-geolocation-with-filtering/50455162#50455162

Comment: Thanks u i will figure out