# How can I make a filter based in the distance with React-native

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-native-maps

I need to create a distance filter for my app, like just getting users from the user city, like in tinder distance radius, how can I do that ?
here is the page code I have for now

```
getUsers = async() => {
    try{
        const response = await api.get('/auth/list')

        const { users } = response.data
        console.log({users})

        this.setState({ users })
    }catch(response){
        this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error })
        console.log(response.data.error)
    } 
  }


 async componentDidMount(){
  this.getUsers()
 }

 render() {
   return(
     <View>
       {!!this.state.errorMessage && <Text>{ this.state.errorMessage }</Text>}
       {this.state.users.filter(user => user.speciality === 'Dermatologista').map(user => (
          <View key={user._id} style={{marginTop: 15, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20}}>{user.title}</Text>
            <Text>{user.speciality}</Text>
            <Button   title = 'View Profile'onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
               name: user._id
               
            })}/>
            </View>
        ))}
     </View>
   )
 }
}
```

how can I make a distance filter too ?, I already have the currentposititon and the other users positions

Comment: Just find the difference between position of current user and other users and store it in array or object. Then sort the array to get your required filter. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452059/sort-data-by-closest-geolocation-with-filtering) as your reference.

Comment: thank you mate, you helped a lot, good morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is simple and you just need to create  a regions array and do the following

this will get the user location

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        ({coords: {latitude, longitude}}) => {
          this.setState({region: {latitude, longitude,latitudeDelta:0.0, 
 longitudeDelta:0.005,}})
        }, //sucesso
        () => {}, //erro
        {
          timeout: 2000,
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          maximumAge: 1000,
        }
      )
    }
    
    render(){
      const users = this.state.users
      console.log(users)
```

and here is the filter

```
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>
          {!!this.state.errorMessage && <text>{this.state.errorMessage}</text>}
          {this.state.users.filter(user => user.speciality === 'Hospital' && 
           user.latitude > this.state.region.latitude - .2 &&
           user.latitude < this.state.region.latitude + .2 && user.longitude > 
            this.state.region.longitude -.2 &&
           user.longitude < this.state.region.longitude + .2
           ).map(user => (
              <View key={user._id} style={{marginTop: 15, alignItems: 
               'center'}}>
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20}}>{user.title} 
                </Text>
                <Text>{user.speciality}</Text>
                <Button   title = 'View Profile'onPress ={() => 
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
                   name: user._id
                   
                })}/>
                </View>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
         
    
        </View>
      )
    }
      
    
    }
```