# Is there an efficient way sort an array of objects by distance to a geographic location using coordinates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

So say I have an array of objects that includes details about individuals. The array is as follows:

```
volunteers = [{name:"john",age:"32",origin:{lat:(some number),lng:(some number)},{name:"tony",age:"34",origin:{lat:(some number),lng:(some number)},{name:"timothy",age:"27",origin:{lat:(some number),lng:(some number)},{name:"pat",age:"35",origin:{lat:(some number),lng:(some number)}
```

These individuals are volunteer firefighters. I'd like to sort this array by their distance to my fire. The fire also has coordinates `fireCoordinates: {lat:(some number),lng:(some number)}`

How do I sort my volunteers array by their distance to the fire?

Edit: I've tried different variations of the Haversine formula so far but they haven't been the cleanest solutions since a relatively large amount of code is required and a tedious loop. Also, I'm not necessarily looking for a positive answer, maybe it can't be done. I'd love to understand why either ways.

Thanks

Comment: you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836146/how-to-sort-array-items-by-longitude-latitude-distance-in-javascripts)

Comment: What have you tried? By now you should have at least researched how to get distance between two points

Comment: I've tried different variations of the Haversine formula. My problem is that its more geared towards finding a distance between 2 points rather than sorting an array using it. But also it's not a compact solution. I was looking for something a bit simpler more tidy.

Comment: @tpliakas I've tried it. But again, its not such clean solution because its geared towards calculating the distance between 2 points. I'm looking at a potential array of 100's of individuals.

Comment: @nizhabib Please show us the code you tried that uses the haversine formula, that appears to be the right approach. Did it not work, or did you just think it wasn't compact enough? And yes, you will need to call the distance calculating function a hundred times, once for each individual location in your array, there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've managed to find a solution with node.js.
I've used the [geolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) package. In it you'll find a function called `orderByDistance(point, arrayOfPoints)`. `point` refers to your target coordinate (in my example, the location of the fire `fireCoordinates`). And `arrayOfPoints` refers an array of coordinates to sort (in my example, the `volunteers` array). I had to change my `volunteers` array a bit, placing the latitude and longitude outside of the variable `origin` in fields that have to be called `latitude` and `longitude` **specifically** (any other field names wont work). In short, in order for the `orderByDistance` function to work, I changed my `volunteers` array to look like this

`volunteers = [{name:"john",age:"32",latitude:(some number),longitude:(some number)},{name:"tony",age:"34",latitude:(some number),longitude:(some number)},{name:"timothy",age:"27",lat:(some number),lng:(some number)},{name:"pat",age:"35",latitude:(some number),longi:(some number)]`

Finally, using the function is easy:

```
volunteers = orderByDistance({ latitude: fireCoordinates.lat, longitude: fireCoordinates.lng }, volunteers);
```

The results will be a new `volunteers` array that is sorted by distance to your `point` coordinates. From closets to furthest.